# How to get Text of selected template variable in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

Grafana version `7.3.3`.
I have a Custom variable created on top of `JSON Datasource`. Below payload I used to populate the variable options `$Project`
`[{"text": "Proj1", "value": "1"}, {"text": "Proj2", "value": "2"}]`.

Now for the templating query I want to use `text` of selected $Project dropdown . For e.g.
`fields.Project:$Project.__text` something like this . But I am only getting the `value` of selected variable `$Project` not the `text`.
Is there is a way to get it .

Answer (score 7):

I have found a solution:

```
${variable_name:text}
```

Comment: Vasyan, where did you get that wisdom? I've spent half an hour reading the docs and didn't get it.

Comment: Here's a description of this functionality in the Grafana docs: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#text